# Wcf DataMember field is list<string>

Tags: wcf, list, field

In a WCF class (with `[DataContract]` attribute) I have this field:

```
[DataMember]
public List<string> XYZ;
```

But when I add a reference to the url of this service, in the Reference.cs file this field becomes

private string[] XYZ;

There must be, as usual, a very subtle reason for this, and I really would like to understand it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option for it in Visual Studio. While you are adding new service reference, click *Advanced...* button in *Add Service Reference* dialog and select how do you want to represent collection types:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you need to select  collection type as System.Collections.Generic.List and Dictionary collection type as System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary